# CircularProgressbar is not working in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, progress-bar

I am trying to implement CircularProgressbar in my react-native code, where I have to display this on a percentage basis, but I am getting the error below:

```
Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `path` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.
```

I am using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-circular-progressbar

```
import { CircularProgressbar, buildStyles } from 'react-circular-progressbar';
<CircularProgressbar
  value={percentage}
  text={`${percentage}%`}
  styles={buildStyles({
    // Rotation of path and trail, in number of turns (0-1)
    rotation: 0.25,
 
    // Whether to use rounded or flat corners on the ends - can use 'butt' or 'round'
    strokeLinecap: 'butt',
 
    // Text size
    textSize: '16px',
 
    // How long animation takes to go from one percentage to another, in seconds
    pathTransitionDuration: 0.5,
 
    // Can specify path transition in more detail, or remove it entirely
    // pathTransition: 'none',
 
    // Colors
    pathColor: `rgba(62, 152, 199, ${percentage / 100})`,
    textColor: '#f88',
    trailColor: '#d6d6d6',
    backgroundColor: '#3e98c7',
  })}
/>
```

Comment: what is `percentage` ?

Comment: can you show code that contains this component too?

Comment: percentage any hard code value  like const percentage = 60;

Comment: ok and edit the question please to include the component that wraps this